# css and html making a picture fit the background

Tags: html, css

How to make an image fit the background. Here is what I have done so far?
Here is my css attempt:

```
#bio{
    min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This is hosted on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy3wrzwv/)

Comment: Why you not try `background-images` ? and also you can do it by `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Welcome to the responsive era. Why 1024px min width?

Comment: @MD ashki I already did that and same result

Comment: @MDAshik here is the outupt with background-images https://jsfiddle.net/oy3wrzwv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good alternative to regular `img` is a `div` with `background-image`, it's easier to position it. Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/oy3wrzwv/3/

And a snippet:

```css
#bio {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
 
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499561385668-5ebdb06a79bc?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1949&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bio"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are trying to make an image the background, you might want to consider removing your HTML code, that is:

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499561385668-5ebdb06a79bc?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1949&q=80" id="bio">
```

And use this as your CSS code:

```
body {
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499561385668-5ebdb06a79bc?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1949&q=80);
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: flex;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

In the code above I also changed the `position` to `flex` so that the image as a whole can be seen and doesn't get hidden, as I had seen when you set it to `fixed` instead. Let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: The problem has not been fixed yet